# Is there any way to do RCS keyword replacement using server side hook (git)?

Tags: git, githooks

I am new to githooks.Using githooks, Is there any possible way to obtain the "Date" that changes has been pushed into master.Where the obtained "Date" needs to be automatically updated into the *.java files whichever has been pushed.

Specifically, the change should look like this:

Before push: `private String DATE="$DATE$"

After push: `private String DATE="$DATE: 2020-05-08 18:19:25 $"

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you want the date of the push? Or the date of the latest commit?

Comment: @Schwern, date of the push.Let say file may pushed it into the master after few days from commit.i want to obtain the date and time of push into master.

Comment: This is an X-Y problem. Your commit process **should not** be writing code. This value should be retrieved at runtime from a configuration file or some other sort of configuration store.

Comment: Look up git 'clean' and 'smudge' filters in gitattributes. But you're probably coming from CVS and let me tell you, it's slow and actually, in corner cases, ends up being error-prone. You're probably better off just realizing that you didn't need this feature to begin with.

Comment: @Mort: i tried with git 'clean' and 'smudge' filters in gitattributes. it doesn't help me to get the commit date of changes pushed it into master.where “smudge” filter will run on checkout.my understanding is by using smudge filter we can get only the commit date....correct me if i am wrong...so i thought of looking into githooks for options..

Comment: Oh, you want date *pushed*. Yeah git doesn't do that. AFAIK, you'll have to store that outside of git in a separate push log. For those of us coming from a cvs/svn background, the way these dates work in git, and the lack of support for corporate centralized workflows can be frustrating. You could store this info in a "git note".

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`post-receive` hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-receive-pack#_post_receive_hook). It gets the old commit ID, new commit ID, and reference being updated on STDIN.

If you want the date of the push, simply print the date when the reference is `refs/heads/master`.

```
#!/bin/sh

while read oval nval ref
do
  if [[ $ref == 'refs/heads/master' ]] then
    date=`date`
    echo "master was updated on $date"
  fi
done
```